# Azure B2C custom login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, migration, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c

I am migrating an existing app using ASP.NET Identity to Azure B2C.

I wanted to migrate the existing user details to Azure AD, when user enter the credential in the Azure b2c login. Is there any way to call custom API on click of the Azure login button? If that is possible, I will call an API which will migrate the data to Azure AD.

I can't do one time migration from existing Identity to Azure B2C as we don't get the password as plain text from the database.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview).
There is a sample for this particular scenario as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration#seamless-migration.
Custom policies do have quite a big learning curve, so this option might require a lot of work from you.

The other option is that you add all users in bulk and require everyone to do a password reset.
This is easier to do for you but will require some work from each user.